# Passing an image uri from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have done the photo taking function, and would like to pass the taken photo's uri to another component to review the taken photo. How can I pass the uri from one component to another?

I tried setting state variable and in parent component, and call the variable using props in child component, but there is Reference Error.

The state variables I declared in Parent Component:

```
state = {
        hasCameraPermission: null,
        type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
        pho: "",
    }
```

This is the button with action in Parent Component:

```
<MaterialCommunityIcons name="circle-outline" 
                            onPress = { () => this.takePhoto() }
                            style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 100 
         }} />
```

The photo taking function in Parent Component:

```
async takePhoto(){
        if(this.camera){
            const photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
            //console.log(photo.uri);
            this.setState({formCam: photo.uri});
            this.setState({pho: photo.uri});
            console.log(this.state.pho);
        }
    }
```

And finally the Image tag that I want my picture to be reviewed in Child Component:

```
 render(){
        return (
            <View>
               <Image source={{uri: props.pho}} 
                      style={{width:300, 
                              height: 300, 
                              justifyContent: 'center', 
                              alignContent: 'center', 
                              top: 50}} />
            </View>
        );
     }
```

I expect the taken photo in parent component to be displayed in child component.

Answer (score 0):

[Download the latest code of image picker from here](https://aboutreact.com/example-of-image-picker-in-react-native/)

Then after getting the image use (In functional component)

```
navigation.navigate('componentname',{image: response.uri});
```

use the above code in both code(select from gallery and capture from camera)

and in another component in which you want to show
do like this

```
const componentname = ({navigation,route}) => {
   const selectedImage = route.params.image;
}
```

Then use this value in Image tag
eg :
`<Image source={{ uri: selectedImage }} style={{width: 200,height: 200}} />`